# How to diff rewrapped text?

Tags: diff, word-wrap

When editing documents I always stick to a certain line width of max 80 or 150 characters, depends what I am writing (code, text, etc.). If I change only a little the whole paragraph will shift and hence multiple lines are now in different order to optimal fit for the given line width. How do I diff this to see the actual real change an not the rewrapping artifacts?

Example, textwidth=30:
[image]

The actual changes are rather tiny:

- line 9 insert: "Now I change a little"
- line 15 insert: "Fill in here something and write totally new stuff with much more lines. "
- line 18 change: s/Duis/TYPO/

The fact that I use (g)vimdiff here is of no matter, if other software can accomplish the desired diff.

Of course software is designed to wrap automatically when text reaches window borders, so I also tried to use just line breaks in the end of a paragraph. The reason why this is not good is, that automatically diffs are line based, and for small changes in paragraphs I get the whole line, meaning then the whole paragraph as diff update :(.

Comment: I don't see any development question here, can you provide more details ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GNU wdiff](https://www.gnu.org/software/wdiff/) does a word-by-word diff, not treating spaces and new lines any differently. One can even find vim syntax files for it (e.g. [here](http://alfie.ist.org/vim/syntax/wdiff.vim)).

```
$ cat file1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
adipiscing elit. Aenean vel molestie
nulla. Pellentesque placerat lacus vel
eros malesuada tristique. Nulla vitae
volutpat justo. Donec est mauris,

$ cat file2
Lorem amet, consectetur adipiscing some
inserted text! elit. Aenean vel molestie
nulla. Pellentesque placerat lacus vel
eros malesuada replacement. Nulla vitae
volutpat justo. Donec est mauris,

$ wdiff file1 file2
Lorem [-ipsum dolor sit-] amet, consectetur
adipiscing {+some inserted text!+} elit. Aenean vel molestie
nulla. Pellentesque placerat lacus vel
eros malesuada [-tristique.-] {+replacement.+} Nulla vitae
volutpat justo. Donec est mauris
```

(`[- ... -]` is deleted text, `{+ ... +}` is inserted text).

(There are other diff programs that do a similar thing: e.g. [adiff](http://agriffis.n01se.net/adiff/), and maybe some of the ones listed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625/best-diff-tool)

Comment: Thanks,.. there is already a newer version for wdiff syntax: http://alfie.ist.org/projects/vim/syntax/wdiff.vim

Answer (score 2):

I like [**Beyond Compare**](http://scootersoftware.com) for this kind of side-by-side file comparison. Also lets you do folder comparisons and bit-level comparisons, and you can right-click to select the left-hand file to compare, then another to select the right-hand one; or select two files and right-click Compare to bring them both up straight away.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use [DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/) which is free and available on many platforms.

[image]